# dynamic columns in @Html.Grid and editable textbox for each column in a row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid

I want to bind a Grid which will have unknown number of columns. 
I have Master Table of Currencies having columns :

(ID NAME)
  1  USD
  2  GEL
  3  MXN
  4  EURO
  5  PKR
logged in user is assigned let say two of those USD and EURO .. 
now there will be 10 textboxes in the grid 5 rows and 2 columns (2 textboxes in each row) .. problem is it is not binding values to all textboxes but just some of them.. any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class ConversionRates
    {
       public string ParentCurrencyName {get;set;}
       public int ParentCurrencyID {get;set;}
       public List<SettlementValues> Values{get;set;}
    }
    public class SettlementValues
    {
       public string ChildCurrencyName {get;set;}
       public string ChildCurrencyID {get;set;}
       public decimal Value {get;set;}
    }
```

**View**

```
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>{
    columns.Add(model => model.ParentCurrencyName).Titled("Parent   Currency").Filterable(true);
    foreach(var item in Model.Values)
    {

       columns.Add(model => item.ChildCurrencyName);

       <input type="text" name="Value" value="@item.Value">
    }
     }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
```